# How do I generate a JaCoCo report for a JAR file?

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

We are trying to report code coverage of tests against a pre-packaged JAR file using JaCoCo. To do this we start the JAR file using `java -jar` with the additional argument:

```
-javaagent:${project.basedir}/tools/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,port=${jacoco.port}
```

JaCoCo's Maven plugin is configured to then dump the execution file and report the results:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>dumpData</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>dump</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <address>localhost</address>
                <port>${jacoco.port}</port>
                <destFile>target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This works to the point that a `jacoco.exec` file is generated which has a non-zero size (~350kB).

But the report shows no coverage at all. Following the "Sessions" link I can see the classes in the JAR listed, but the report's home page shows this:
[image: JaCoCo Report]

Based on the logs we have the code seems to be exercised. Is there a step missing in the JaCoCo setup or should this work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve with that `-javaagent`. It should get coverage from tests - did you read http://www.baeldung.com/jacoco ? So during the Maven build, you are running tests and based on those tests coverage is measured. This is typical usage as I know it...

Comment: I'm doing black-box testing against an already built JAR file. We are starting up a Spring Boot application and hit it with HTTP requests, I'm trying to measure the code coverage of that. Not a typical usage, but as far as I understand the documentation it should be doable. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I have no experience with that, maybe you can look at https://carlosbecker.com/posts/production-code-coverage-jacoco/ ;-)

Comment: Running the report from the CLI tool, pointing the "--classfiles" to the JAR, I get an exeption "Error while analyzing ....app.jar@BOOT-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar@org/aopalliance/aop/AspectException.class" - it looks like it can't handle the way Spring Boot packages classes. Maybe that's why my report is empty.

Comment: any solution on that?

Comment: Sorry, I should have documented the answer. Now I have moved on, and I don't remember what we did. We had coverage reports in the end, but I don't even remember if we stuck with JaCoCo or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to achieve this:

1. Run the java application in a separate JVM with `-javaagent` parameter passed.
2. Run your tests against the application(like calling an endpoint on the web server, etc.)
3. Run the `dump` and `report` goals to generate the report.

You can check out [my article](https://www.thecodejournal.tech/2022/04/jacoco-maven-plugin-dump-goal-configurations/) on the this topic.